# How to use ng-file-upload with a factory?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add factory to my "ng-file-upload" controller (really a copy-paste from their documentation)... But unfortunately it won't work for me

**Here is some code example**

Factory:

```
weekly_report_app.factory('sharedData', function () {

    var data = {
        value: "initial value"
    };

    return {
        getValue: function() { 
           return data.value; 
        },
        updateValue: function(value) {
           data.value = value;
        }
    };
});
```

Controller:

```
weekly_report_app.controller('uploadCtrl', [ '$scope', 'Upload', 'sharedData',  function($scope, Upload, sharedData) {

   $scope.attachments_counter = 0;

   $scope.$watch('files', function () {
       $scope.upload($scope.files);
   });  

    $scope.upload = function (files) {
      if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            $scope.attachments_counter++;

            sharedData.getValue(); // Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/$injector/unpr?p0=sharedDataProvider%20%3C-%20sharedData%20%3C-%20uploadCtrl
            var file = files[i];
            Upload.upload({
                url: 'uploads',
                fields: {
                            'username': "test_name",
                            'team': "test_team",
                            'project_name': "test_project",
                            'task_name': "test_task"
                        },
                file: file
            }).progress(function (evt) {
                var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name);
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded successfuly. Response: ' + data);
            });
        }
    }
};
}]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add 'proxyService' to the list of strings in your controller definition

Comment: I see what you mean... I removed it from the array because I  got another error (which is solved if I replace 'factory' to be a 'service'). Edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a plnkr of your code as at the moment it looks like you just have a dependency issue.